# How do I add the values of two integer columns in Informix?

Tags: informix

I would like to add two integer columns in a table with the database Informix (IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 14.10) , let's call these table articles. The first column is price and the second column is tax. From this I would like to calculate the total price for an article.

The table for articles looks like this:

| id | name | price | tax |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | 50 | 6 |
| 2 | banana | 20 | 3 |
| 3 | ... | ... | ... |

How would the SQL statement in Informix look like for this?

How is this expression called in Informix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Informix, you can add the values of two integer columns in a table using a `SELECT` statement. Here's an example query that demonstrates how to do this:

```
sql:-
SELECT column1 + column2 AS sum_result
FROM your_table;
```

Replace `your_table` with the actual name of your table, and `column1` and `column2` with the names of the integer columns you want to add. The result will be a new column named `sum_result` containing the sum of the values from `column1` and `column2`.

Here's a breakdown of the SQL statement:

- `SELECT`: Specifies the columns to retrieve.
- `column1 + column2 AS sum_result`: Performs the addition of `column1` and `column2` and assigns the result to a new column named `sum_result`.
- `FROM your_table`: Specifies the table from which to retrieve the data. Replace `your_table` with the actual name of your table.
  Make sure to adapt the column and table names according to your database schema.